# How do I execute a .scm script (outside of the REPL) with MIT-Scheme?

Tags: scheme, mit-scheme

I want to type something like 'scheme file.scm' and have it interpret the file, and then take me back to my shell, rather than loading it in the REPL.

edit: I tried scheme < test.scm and it still uses the REPL, the only difference is that scheme exits when the stream ends.

Answer (score 51):

`scheme < file.scm` should work (as long as you don't specify `--interactive` and stdin is not a terminal, scheme works non-interactively).

Comment: This doesn't fulfill the OP's edited requirement of "not using the REPL". See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47724861/5916915).

Answer (score 17):

To run a scheme program using MIT Scheme:

```
scheme --quiet < program.scm
```

The `--quiet` option ensures that the output from your program is the only thing that is displayed (i.e. you won't see the REPL, as per your requirements).

**Caveat**: This will not work if your program prompts the user for input using the input procedures (e.g. `read`, `read-char`, `read-line`, etc.). This is because of the shell input redirection (`<`) (See: [relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57837383/how-to-use-read-correctly-in-mit-scheme)). Unfortunately, there is currently no proper way of executing an MIT Scheme script from the command line when input  procedures are used. The best option is probably `mit-scheme --quiet --load 'myscript'`, but you'd have to manually exit MIT Scheme when the script finishes. Relevant mailing list thread: [[MIT-Scheme-devel] How to run a script and exit?](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/mit-scheme-devel/2019-09/msg00000.html)

EDIT: Due to the possibility that you may mistype `<` as `>`, resulting in the overwrite of your source code, I would suggest encapsulating the above command within a shell script or a shell function. For example:

```
runscheme () {
    scheme --quiet < "$1"
}
```

Then you can run `runscheme program.scm` without fear that your source code will be overwritten. (Special thanks to [Paul Rooney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1540468/) for bringing this potential mistake to my attention).

#### References

`scheme --help`:

> --batch-mode, --quiet, --silent
>
> Suppresses the startup report of versions and copyrights, and the
>   valediction.

This command line option seems to have been mistakenly ommitted from the [list of command line options in the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-user/Command_002dLine-Options.html), but I think this is a legimate command line option because `scheme --help` shows it, and because `--batch-mode` is used in other parts of the reference manual (e.g. [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ffi/Compiling-and-Linking.html)).

Comment: don't get the `<` the wrong way around or you will overwrite your own source code, or is it only me that does stuff like that?

Comment: @PaulRooney If you tend to make such mistakes, I would suggest writing a shell script or shell function for running your Scheme programs. Example shell function: `runscheme () { scheme --quiet < "$1" }`.

Comment: ok thank you. I dont tend to make such mistakes too often. Sorry it was not a criticism of the answer. I just did it and it made me laugh when I realised what had happened.

Comment: @PaulRooney Edited the answer so that others can avoid such mistakes in the future. Thank you for bringing this to my attention.

Comment: sorry I really didnt intend for you to change the answer. I just thought it was amusing. I would upvote, but I did that already.

Answer (score 8):

I think what you want is SCM. You can execute a .scm script like this:

`$ scm -f foo.scm arg1 arg2 arg3`

See http://people.csail.mit.edu/jaffer/scm_3.html#SEC28 for more details.

The SCM homepage: http://people.csail.mit.edu/jaffer/SCM

Comment: Strange thing, but it doesn't work without -f for me. Note this, guys.

Comment: The question is about MIT Scheme, and not about SCM.

Answer (score 0):

checked `chez --help`, and then I found this(let's say that I'm using chez scheme):

```
chez --script ./temp.scm
```

Also, `--verbose` is very useful:

```
chez --verbose --script ./temp.scm
```

Comment: The question is about MIT Scheme, and not about Chez Scheme.