# mit-scheme -- run a script and exit

Tags: mit-scheme

I want to evaluate a script from makefile and exit, like this

```
mit-scheme --load "fact.scm"
```

However, after it evaluates the file, it does not exit, and the repl appears; if I try the `(exit)` primitive, it asks for confirmation y/n. Is it possible to solve this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I execute a .scm script (outside of the REPL) with MIT-Scheme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903968/how-do-i-execute-a-scm-script-outside-of-the-repl-with-mit-scheme)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Unix mit-scheme reads the input files via redirection:

`mit-scheme < /usr/cph/foo.in > /usr/cph/foo.out 2>&1 &`

This is taken from the documentation http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-user/Command_002dLine-Options.html#Command_002dLine-Options

Answer (score 8):

Just let our command close stdin of the mit-scheme process automatically, e.g.

```
echo | mit-scheme --load sample.scm
```

We can expand it to a script function; here's my unskilled implementation:

```
function mschm () {
   IFS=""
   for arg in $@
       do
           echo | mit-scheme --load $arg
       done
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This works; at least under 11.2, I don't get any confirmation prompt on the `(exit)`:

```
scheme --quiet --load filename --eval '(exit)'
```

I have this handy-dandy shell function that provides a pseudo-pythonic invocation experience: with no args it drops me into the REPL, but if there is an argument, the first one is taken as a script name and any subsequent args turn into `(command-line-arguments)`. This is the definition; as written it works in bash, ksh, or zsh:

```
function scm {
  if (( $# )); then
    typeset prog=$1
    shift
    scheme --quiet --load "$prog" --eval '(exit)' -- "$@"
  else
    scheme
  fi
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add the `--quiet` argument to the `mit-scheme` command to suppress the default output. This is otherwise a crib of Charlie Forthmount's function (though it only loads one file):

```
run-mit-scheme () 
{ 
    echo | mit-scheme --quiet --load $1;
    # Add an extra newline
    echo
}
```

Comment: If you aren't an Emacs person, I suggest using Dr. Racket with the sicp package for a full IDE experience instead of a script like this. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/262886/2958070