# How do you use mit / gnu scheme in non repl mode?

Tags: scheme, mit-scheme

I have a file called test.scm that looks like:

```
(display 5)
```

and when I go like this

```
cat test.scm | scheme
```

or like this

```
scheme < test.scm
```

or like this

```
cat test.scm | scheme > output.txt
```

I get

```
MIT/GNU Scheme running under GNU/Linux
Type `^C' (control-C) followed by `H' to obtain information about interrupts.

Copyright (C) 2011 Massachusetts Institute of Technology
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Image saved on Sunday February 7, 2016 at 10:35:34 AM
  Release 9.1.1     || Microcode 15.3 || Runtime 15.7 || SF 4.41
  LIAR/x86-64 4.118 || Edwin 3.116

1 ]=> 5
;Unspecified return value

1 ]=> 
End of input stream reached.
Moriturus te saluto.
```

What do I have to do to get the following?

```
5
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I execute a .scm script (outside of the REPL) with MIT-Scheme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903968/how-do-i-execute-a-scm-script-outside-of-the-repl-with-mit-scheme)

Answer (score 1):

Tricky question. I have tried a little but I have problems getting it to behave like other Scheme implementations I currently use. If you are ok with the verbose output you can just do:

```
scheme --load "file.scm"
```

Now. I usually use `plt-r5rs` and `plt-r6rs` to just run stuff and `raco exe` to make an executable for my machine:

```
plt-r5rs r5rs-program.scm # interpreted r5rs
plt-r6rs r6rs-program.scm # interpreted r6rs
raco exe any-scheme-program.scm
./any-scheme-program # faster executable
```

I also use ikarus sometimes since its sometimes faster than compiled racket:

```
ikarus --r6rs-script r6rs-program.scm # jit compiled r6rs
```

In your question you are trying to use shell pipe and redirection. These redirect stdio/stdout/stderr from to file or pipe to another program and *not scheme source code to be run*. This works with both racket and ikarus:

```
cat file1 file2 | ikarus --r6rs-script r6rs-echo.scm | wc -l 
plt-r6rs r6rs-echo.scm < file | wc -l 
plt-r5rs wcl.scm < file > file-count.txt
```

Note that there are lots of other [scheme implementations](http://community.schemewiki.org/?scheme-faq-standards#implementations) conforming to R5RS, R6RS and even R7RS that does this as well. It's been a while since I used mit-scheme and it certainly will be a good while before I start it again with so many other options.