# How to make output in mit-scheme less verbose when it's used for running script

Tags: scheme, sicp, mit-scheme

I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260685/what-is-the-best-scheme-implementation-for-working-through-sicp) where people recommend to use mit-scheme for solving exercises from SICP. After doing some python and ruby I'm wondering is it possible to use mit-scheme interpreter/compiler in the same manner how can be used ruby or python? By this I mean simply write the script in vim and run `mit-scheme my_script.scm` in terminal to see the output.

*update*

Seems like `mit-scheme < my_script.scm` does what I was looking for, but its output is too verbose.
Ideally, I'd like to see in the output only things which I deliberately sent to `stdout`.

Comment: Yes, it opens repl. I was looking for something similar to running script using python or ruby's interpreter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the `--silent` flag.

Usage: `mit-scheme --silent < my-script.scm`

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for misleading title, I fixed it a bit.