# which Lisp dialect should I use and *how* should I get started for SICP? I use Dr. Racket & know a little Racket

Tags: emacs, lisp, racket, sicp

I've been working with **Dr. Racket** (just started) for the "Programming Languages" MOOC on Coursera through University of Washington. So I'm just starting to learn the **Racket** language. In tandem with that I'd like to start reading **SICP** and watching the **lecture videos on MIT OCW from 1986**. I'm wondering **what dialect of Lisp** I should use so I'll be able to have a fairly seamless experience going from the video lectures on MIT OCW to **Emacs** or **Dr. Racket**. [That's essentially my question]. What would people recommend? Especially people who have watched the 1986 lectures, have read SICP cover to cover and worked at least some exercises, and ideally also are familiar with Dr. Racket, Racket and possibly multiple dialects of Lisp and Scheme but I'm open to all opinions.

Comment: Possible duplicate. This question has been asked before, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19546115/which-lang-packet-is-proper-for-sicp-in-dr-racket) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260685/what-is-the-best-scheme-implementation-for-working-through-sicp).

Comment: There are specific issues I have with all of their answers. MIT Scheme doesn't have support since like Windows XP and I'm sadly on 7 & 8. My Linux machine died (it has issues in Linux anyway). I was hoping by asking a more specific question I might get answers that are more apropos of what I'm trying to do in 2014. I want to go straight from video lectures created in 1986 and the SICP book to working in Dr. Racket or Emacs and not have to be learning the differences between modern dialects of Racket or Scheme and 1986 Lisp at the same time.

Comment: Try using DrRacket with the SICP [compatibility language](http://www.neilvandyke.org/racket-sicp), you won't have to learn a different dialect for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I read through SICP and did all the exercises using PLT Scheme, although back then it was called Dr Scheme rather than Dr Racket. And I'd recommend it whole-heartedly. EMACS is great (my main editor), but learning it is harder than learning scheme. And it's best to have only the one problem to solve.

I used R4RS scheme, which was closest to the version in SICP.

If that's still in the latest version then you should be fine. If not then just about anything calling itself scheme will do.

I think you won't hit that many problems using Racket itself until chapter 3, where they start using things like set-car!, but if you get that far you'll probably be able to work out what's going on yourself by then.

---

Edit:

Just to check, I've just tried it on my Debian box:
R4RS is missing, but R5RS should be fine.

```
$ sudo apt-get install plt-scheme
```

Windows install should be easier, since ease of use is Windows' selling point...

Run Dr Racket

```
$ drracket
```

DrRacket version 5.3.6
says 'No language chosen'
Navigate to:

```
Language/Choose Language/Other Languages/Legacy Languages/R5RS
```

type:

```
(define (factorial n)
  (if (< n 2) 1
      (* n (factorial (- n 1)))))
```

into the top window

Press Run

type:

```
(factorial 10)
```

into the bottom window and press return, and it should give you

```
3628800
```

That's hello world for Scheme, and if you can get that working then you should be ok for the first chapters of the book.

As I remember there was a recursive graphics exercise somewhere which was a bit of a sod to get working, but it can be done. Just skip over it. Everything else should be fine.

If you run into any trouble get in touch and I'll show you how to get through it.

Good luck!

Comment: Sweet! You have a new reader for your blog good Sir, I just decided today that Clojure is the next language I'm excited to learn! :-)

Comment: *earlier today. The computer gods must have smiled upon my decision. I was watching this chat: http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Going+Deep/Expert-to-Expert-Rich-Hickey-and-Brian-Beckman-Inside-Clojure/

Comment: Insteead of R4RS there is now a #lang especifically for SICP http://www.neilvandyke.org/racket-sicp/