# How to create a sicp-flavoured racket script and have it output a single value?

Tags: scheme, command-line-interface, racket, sicp

I'm trying to create a simple [sicp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/260685/275088)-flavoured scheme script that outputs a single value:

```
$ cat test.scm 
#lang sicp
(+ 1 2 3)
```

When I run it with `racket test.scm`, it doesn't output the result (`"6"`). How should I be writing/running the script?

Comment: Have you tried `(display (+ 1 2 3))` ?

Comment: @Óscar this almost works when I do `racket < test.scm`, but still outputs a lot of garbage. I need to output just the value.

Comment: Running `racket test.scm` on a file with that content prints `6` for me. What OS are you running and which version of Racket are you using?

Comment: "a lot of garbage" <- can you be more specific?

Comment: I have racket v.6.5 on an ArchLinux box. When I do `racket test.scm` I get: `racket test.scm 
standard-module-name-resolver: collection not found
  for module path: (submod sicp reader)
  collection: "sicp"
  in collection directories:
   /home/user/.racket/6.5/collects
   /usr/share/racket/collects
   ... [155 additional linked and package directories]
  context...:
   show-collection-err
   standard-module-name-resolver`

Comment: ..and `racket < test.scm` gives me: 
`Welcome to Racket v6.5.
> stdin::1: read: #lang not enabled in the current context
  context...:
   /usr/share/racket/collects/racket/private/misc.rkt:87:7
> sicp: undefined;
 cannot reference undefined identifier
  context...:
   /usr/share/racket/collects/racket/private/misc.rkt:87:7
> 6>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is deeper than it seems. The installation of the `sicp` module is incorrect, and/or the language configuration is wrong.

Try running the same code using DrRacket's GUI before running it from the command line. And try reinstalling the `sicp` module following the instructions in the documentation.